# React hook useEffect for fetching data does not work for fetching data from different APIs, maybe a loop problem

Tags: react-hooks

I am learning React hooks and trying to fetch info about countries from one API and weather for these countries from another. I use useState to store this data.

```
const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]) 

*//use the first hook to get data on countries*    
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
        setCountries(response.data)
      })
  }, [])

*//want to use the second hook to get weather for all the countries fetched in the first hook*
  useEffect(() => {
    countries.forEach(country => {
      axios
        .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=**${country.capital}**&units=metric&APPID=myAPI`)
        .then(response => {
          const temp = response.data.main.temp
*//concat method does not seem to be working on the next line*
          **setWeather(weather.concat(temp))**
        })
    })
  }, [countries])
*//when I console.log I get temperature for only the last city in the loop and not an array as I expect*
  console.log(weather)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```js
setWeather(weather.concat(temp));
```

The variable `weather` is not garantized to be updated. Pass the previous value of the state to make the concatenation:

```js
setWeather((previousWeatherState) => [...previousWeatherState, temp])
```

The final code of the `useEffect` would be:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    countries.forEach(country => {
      axios
        .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${country.capital}&units=metric&APPID=myAPI`)
        .then(response => {
          const temp = response.data.main.temp
          setWeather((previousWeatherState) => [...previousWeatherState, temp])
        })
    })
  }, [countries])
```